# Can we export mql query output to Google Docs

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, freebase-acre

I am trying to create a freebase acre application which can keep track of certain users records and export the mql query output to Google Docs.

Is it possible to export mql query output to Google Docs in acre?

Edit #1

I found out this [doc](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-js) by which i can export data to Google Docs using javascript.

Edit #2

I am able to upload files to drive but i need to create a Spreadsheet with it. Could it be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible using Google Drive SDK. I am successful in exporting the query output but not able to share the code here.

Answer (score 0):

If you can export the results as CSV, you can create a Google Spreadsheet with them. The important point is to remember to set:

```
convert=true
```

Query parameter on insertion which will ensure that your file is converted correctly to a GOogle Spreadsheet.